# Ошибка при подключении к Базе Данных RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, веб-программирование, сервер, phpmyadmin, redbeanphp

Разработал сайт, он лежит на сервере. База данных к нему находится на другом сервере. При подключении указываю верные логин и пароль от phpMyAdmin, они подходят, так как и другие сайты подключаются по ним. Но выходит ошибка "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'webmaster'@'172.30.239.189' (using password: YES) in C:\OpenServer\domains\ic\php\add.php on line 9
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'webmaster'@'172.30.239.189' (using password: YES)".
Для работы с базой данных используется ORM RedBeanPHP.
Подключаюсь следующим образом:

```
R::setup('mysql: host=' . $connection_setting['server'] .'; dbname=' . $connection_setting['name_db'], $connection_setting['login'], $connection_setting['password']);
```

Так же пробовал не использовать ORM и подключался так:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($connection_setting['server'], $connection_setting['login'], $connection_setting['password'], $connection_setting['name_db']);

if (!$conn) {
     die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }
```

Прошу помочь, уже второй день не могу с этим разобраться.

Comment: В вашем коде ошибки нет. Для начала попробуйте перевести "Access denied for user 'webmaster'"

Comment: В настройках базы выдай пользователю 'webmaster'@'172.30.239.189'  права на доступ. Ясно и четко пишет, что у такого пользователя нет прав.